# How to define areas inside TinyMce

Tags: tinymce

is it possoble to set the editable area of TinyMce to have different areas like this:

[image]

I tried setting creating differeent areas inside the the area I made editable with TinyMce, but the user was able to delete those areas. (e.g with the rightclick delete Table).

This is the html I used for creating the TinyMce area:

```
    <div id="elm1" name="elm1" style="width: 80%" class="tinymce">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><h1>Hello world</h1></td>
            </tr>
            <td> Nam nisi elit, cursus in rhoncus sit amet, pulvinar laoreet leo. Nam sed lectus quam, ut sagittis tellus. Quisque dignissim mauris a augue rutrum tempor. Donec vitae purus nec massa vestibulum ornare sit amet id tellus. Nunc quam mauris, fermentum nec lacinia eget, sollicitudin nec ante. Aliquam molestie volutpat dapibus. Nunc interdum viverra sodales. Morbi laoreet pulvinar gravida. Quisque ut turpis sagittis nunc accumsan vehicula. Duis elementum congue ultrices. Cras faucibus feugiat arcu quis lacinia. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Pellentesque fermentum magna sit amet tellus varius ullamcorper. Vestibulum at urna augue, eget varius neque. Fusce facilisis venenatis dapibus. Integer non sem at arcu euismod tempor nec sed nisl. Morbi ultricies, mauris ut ultricies adipiscing, felis odio condimentum massa, et luctus est nunc nec eros. </td>
            <td> Nam nisi elit, cursus in rhoncus sit amet, pulvinar laoreet leo. Nam sed lectus quam, ut sagittis tellus. Quisque dignissim mauris a augue rutrum tempor. Donec vitae purus nec massa vestibulum ornare sit amet id tellus. Nunc quam mauris, fermentum nec lacinia eget, sollicitudin nec ante. Aliquam molestie volutpat dapibus. Nunc interdum viverra sodales. Morbi laoreet pulvinar gravida. Quisque ut turpis sagittis nunc accumsan vehicula. Duis elementum congue ultrices. Cras faucibus feugiat arcu quis lacinia. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Pellentesque fermentum magna sit amet tellus varius ullamcorper. Vestibulum at urna augue, eget varius neque. Fusce facilisis venenatis dapibus. Integer non sem at arcu euismod tempor nec sed nisl. Morbi ultricies, mauris ut ultricies adipiscing, felis odio condimentum massa, et luctus est nunc nec eros. </td>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: It seems even the [noneditable plugin example](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/noneditable_content.php) allows you to delete the non-editable parent node (but not edit it). This stuff is such a chore, can't all our clients just learn HTML? ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, but you will have to take care of the non-deletion yourself using an own plugin. For this you will need to intercept all possible deletion events like (backspace, delete, copy/paste, selecting + typing, cmd+x) and handle them yourself which is quite some work.

Comment: well, I was afraid of this answer.... I think I will use a niceEdit, as my editor of choice, insce it allowes to define the editable html elements... but only has 10% of the features of tinyMce.... NiceEdit link: http://nicedit.com/

(PS I will accept the answer later, in case somebody still knows something, which I don't expect)

Comment: it works pretty well for what I need for, so we decided to used. Peronally I'd prefer TinyMce because it looks way better supported and consitant :) (without actually using it much yet)